# Does modify work only if I redeclare the data type?

Tags: mysql, sql, alter

In order to change the order of a column the following works:

```
ALTER TABLE contacts  
MODIFY COLUMN id VARCHAR(20) FIRST;
```

The following:

```
ALTER TABLE my_contacts
MODIFY COLUMN id FIRST;
```

Gives me the error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'FIRST' at line 2

I was wondering, is it not possible to change the order of a column *without* re-declaring its data-type?
Are all modifications of a column have the re-declaring of the data type as mandatory?

Answer (score 2):

Your intuition is correct. An ALTER statement must be explicit in the full type of the column.

From the documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html

```
 MODIFY [COLUMN] col_name column_definition
        [FIRST | AFTER col_name]
```

column_definition is mandatory.